# How to Place a button next to ListItem

Tags: asp.net, html, css, button, webforms

How I place a button next to each list item?

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="lstBrembo" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Popular" Value="9"></asp:ListItem> // <--- button here
    <asp:ListItem Text="Pads" Value="70"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Discs" Value="72"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Drums" Value="73"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Handed Discs" Value="109"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Brembo Max" Value="108"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

every time I try and insert a  after the list item, or inside it, I get an parse error. I need a button there somehow.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div id="MainContentPlaceHolder_pnlBrembo" class="groupbox">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            BREMBO
        </legend>
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ctl02" value="select all" class="selectAllButton" />
    <table id="MainContentPlaceHolder_lstBrembo">
            <tr>
                <td><input id="MainContentPlaceHolder_lstBrembo_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$lstBrembo$0" value="9" /><label for="MainContentPlaceHolder_lstBrembo_0">Popular</label></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="MainContentPlaceHolder_lstBrembo_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$lstBrembo$1" value="70" /><label for="MainContentPlaceHolder_lstBrembo_1">Pads</label></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="MainContentPlaceHolder_lstBrembo_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$lstBrembo$2" value="72" /><label for="MainContentPlaceHolder_lstBrembo_2">Discs</label></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="MainContentPlaceHolder_lstBrembo_3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$lstBrembo$3" value="73" /><label for="MainContentPlaceHolder_lstBrembo_3">Drums</label></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="MainContentPlaceHolder_lstBrembo_4" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$lstBrembo$4" value="109" /><label for="MainContentPlaceHolder_lstBrembo_4">Handed Discs</label></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="MainContentPlaceHolder_lstBrembo_5" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$lstBrembo$5" value="108" /><label for="MainContentPlaceHolder_lstBrembo_5">Brembo Max</label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste rendered output (HTML)?

Comment: @Muhammad I think this is not possible.

Comment: @SowmyaShivaram pasted HTML for you.

Comment: use repeater and inside repeater place checkbox list

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas for the added functionality all that extra complexity ... is not worth the effort, especially since I want to fill the lists from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian Mains said use repeater or listview insted

Here's simple example for ListView:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvBrembo" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="lstBrembo" border="0">
                <tbody runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chbSelection" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' Checked='<%# Eval("selected") %>' runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDetails" Text='<%# Eval("link") %>' runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Class used in example:

```
class Brembo
    {
        public string name {get;set;}
        public string link {get;set;}
        public bool selected {get;set;}
        public int value {get;set;}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an alternative control like the ListView or Repeater for this instead.  The default checkBoxList won't give you this ability easily.  With a data bound control, you can format it however you want.

Comment: I used a DataRepeater in the end, its simpler as just what I needed. Thanks.